# Identify overlap sequence

Tags: python, sequence, overlap

I have a question, I am building a program where I want to identify the overlapped sequence of two lists.

sequ_1 = 'blablablaaaabla'

seque_2 = 'aaablaccbla'

The expected output would be: 'aaabla'

I created this function that would tell me whether or not the sequence from the sequ_2 overlaps with sequ_1:

` def overlap (sequ_1, sequ_2):

```
count_overlapp = 0 
count_nooverlapp = 0 
for i in range(len(sequ_1)-len(sequ_2)+1): 
    if loci1[i:i+len(sequ_1)]==sequ_2: 
        count_overlapp= count_overlapp+1 
    else: count_nooverlapp = count_nooverlapp +1 
return print(f'The number of overlapped sequence:{count_overlapp}\nThe number of not overlapped sequence:{count_nooverlapp}')`
```

But it only computes well if the sequ_2 is within sequ_1, but it doesnt if sequ_2 is partially overlaps sequ_1

What would be great is to identify the sequence that overlapps as well

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solution is that you need:

```
sequ_1 = 'blablablaaaabla'
seque_2 = 'aaablaccbla'


overlap = ""

for i in range(len(seque_2)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(seque_2)):
        tmp = seque_2[i:j+1]
        if len(tmp) > len(overlap) and tmp in sequ_1:
            overlap = tmp

print(overlap)
```

Output: aaabla